# open the Image from the HDF5 file using Labview

Tags: image, hdf5, labview

The link for the HDF file is provided below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tKgM60_6qObpDNwpJNxGxlMi6cIWg0dX/view?usp=sharing
How can i obtain the image from it in LabVIEW? If you need addition information, please let me know.
While there may be other methods, I specifically want to accomplish this in the LabVIEW as it is part of my course

I am new to the LabVIEW, so i am finding it challenging to use
Thank you!